# Can't get Knockout.js to update an observable object property

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an object with a public property:

```
function MyClass() {
    var self = this;
    self.test = 'foo';
    self.changeTest = function() {self.test = 'bar';}
}

var myobj = new MyClass();
```

The property can be accessed by some of the objects methods and from the "outside". Now, if I create and bind a View Model like this:

```
function AppVMClass() {
    var self = this;
    self.obs_obj = ko.observable(myobj);
}
var vmodel = new AppVMClass();
ko.applyBindings(vmodel);
```

then invoking `myobj.changeTest()` wont change the value of observable.
I.e. if I have something like that in HTML page:
    `< div data-binding="text: obs_obj().test"></div>` it would display "foo" even after `myobj.changeTest()` has been invoked instead of updating.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ko.observable` has no way of knowing when you've modified `myobj` - you have to "tell" it. Normally, this is done by using the observable directly when you modify a property. This really only makes sense for values (like `self.test`), but you're attempting to have an entire object be the observable.

Instead, break out the values that you care about into their own observables, either on the ViewModel or on a separate object if you really care about the separation:

```
function MyClass() {
    var self = this;
    // Notice that we're creating an observable directly,
    // and setting its value in the changeTest method.
    self.test = ko.observable('foo');
    self.changeTest = function() {self.test('bar');}
}

var myobj = new MyClass();

function AppVMClass() {
    var self = this;
    self.obs_obj = myobj;
}
```

And change your template (note, don't do `obs_obj.test()`, as that will just return the value - you want to bind to the *observable itself*):

```
<div data-bind="text: obs_obj.test"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I assumed that Knockout used some JS introspection features to check whether observable value has changed (and attached change listeners in ko.observable function). Your answer makes much more sense, though.

Comment: @monday: As an interesting note, some other JS libraries choose to use exactly that kind of dirty checking for their data binding - namely, AngularJS.

Comment: It's also useful to know that in the (rare) case where you do need to modify members of an observable, you can tell Knockout that the observable has mutated with myobj.valueHasMutated().

Comment: @monday cleaner way to construct vm try this http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/24316/ . #voithos good one . cheers